# Changing font of a button

Tags: html

I'm new and I've been trying to change the font of my button but it does not seem to work when I use the style attribute. Can someone tell me how I can change the font of the text within my button? Thank you!

```
<a style="font-family: Times New Roman" class = "btn btn-light" href="{% url 'update_task' task.id %}">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `font-family` property-value is a white-space separated list of font names. As you have spaces in the name of your preferred font you have to quote that name, to give:

```
font-name: font-family: "Times New Roman";
```

Otherwise the browser parses it as a list of fonts comprising of the `Times` font, the `New` font and the `Roman` font, which it probably won't find installed your system.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing apostrophes in the font name: ''

```
<a style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'" class = "btn btn-light" href="{% url 'update_task' task.id %}">Edit</a>
```